# Firebase Database for Unity3d Android ValueChanged unsubscribe issues

Tags: android, database, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have problem with Unity3d SDK.
I subscribe to ValueChanged event and when first time it invokes I unsubscribe from the handler.
In Unity everything works fine.
But when I build project for Android, unsubscribe fails: after unsubscribe I still handle events in handler.
Here is the code:

```
public void CheckUserExists()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
        .GetReference("users").Child(primary_key)
        .ValueChanged += CheckUserExistsHadler;
}

void CheckUserExistsHadler(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
        .GetReference("users").Child(primary_key)
        .ValueChanged -= CheckUserExistsHadler;

    if (e.Snapshot == null || e.Snapshot.Value == null)
    {
        print("user_exists");
    }
    else
    {
        print("user_not_exists");
    }
}
```

Comment: A bug or maybe `primary_key` changed in the `CheckUserExistsHadler` function?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tip. I changed to

```
user_reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").Child(primary_key); 
...
user_reference.ValueChanged += CheckUserExistsHadler; 
...
user_reference.ValueChanged -= CheckUserExistsHadler;
```

and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I Just ran into this issue on Android, worked in Editor.

What I found was that when I re-created the database reference at the point of un-subscribing, using the exact same reference string as I used to add the listener it would not properly un-subscribe in Android.

The solution I used was the same as Bestlis above, I created a DatabaseReference variable, which I used to sub and un-sub from, now it works.

It's an odd problem to have, it's like `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference` changes during operation?

Comment: basically the docs are lying to us when they say they are ephemeral and equivalent for purpose of unsub :) ? "You can later unsubscribe from the event using any DatabaseReference that has the same path. DatabaseReference instances are ephemeral and can be thought of as a way to access any path and query." NOOOOOOO!!!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, any firebase calls made from a callback fail(Getvalue, updatechildren, subscribe/unsubscribe, all that). Your best bet is to have it put into an action queue, and have a monobehavior check the queue/list and call its contents from the main thread.